# Save list of numpy arrays onto disk

Tags: python, list, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have a list of `42000` **numpy** arrays (each array is `240x240`) that I want to save to a file for use in another python script.

I've tried using `pickle` and `numpy.savez_compressed` and I run into Memory Errors (I have 16gb DDR3). I read that `hdf5` which is commonly used for deep learning stuff cannot save lists so I'm kind of stuck.

Does anyone have any idea how I can save my data?

EDIT: I previously saved this data into a numpy array onto disk using `np.save` and it was around 2.3GB but my computer couldn't always handle it so it would sometimes crash if I tried to process it. I read lists might be better so I have moved to using lists of numpy arrays

Comment: Create a 1-D numpy array out of the list

Comment: I ran into another memory error. When I previously tried this using numpy arrays and saved to disk as .npy it was around 2.3GB.

Comment: Have you tried saving in a .mat file using scipy.io.savemat? You can save all 42000 matrices separately in one directory and then you may read that directory in the new script.  
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html
You can do compression as well using scipy.io.savemat

Comment: You can use numpy.memmap to avoid allocating data into RAM when arrays get too big.

Comment: Try saving chunks. Each file for example being a 1-D array of 100 of your numpy arrays

Comment: I will try to save chunks but this is the ground truth data to my deep neural network so I will eventually need to stack all the data together for training (as I have 5 of these lists of 42000 numpy arrays) and I think I will probably run into another MemoryError. Is there a way to keep appending my data to an excel file or something like hdf5?

Comment: "I read lists might be better..." Where did your read this? Normally it is the opposite way around. Maybe that was a special case, where somebody missused numpy arrays (eg. concatenating or stacking arrays in a loop which leads to excessive memory copying overhead)

Comment: @max9111 I think it was somewhere on stackexchange and the usecase was rather than building a bigger numpy array, just keep appending to a list to create a list of numpy arrays. I'm not sure why it works better but it doesn't take as long as building a bigger numpy array! :)

Comment: Everytime you append some data to a numpy array, a bigger array gets allocated and the whole content of the former array gets copied into the new one. (Quite the same like in C) In a very simplyfied way (hopefully not too simplified) a list can be seen as a pointer array to the actual data which is packed in objects. You should therefore always allocate an np.array first and than copy the data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we have a list of `numpy` arrays, `A`, and wish to save these sequentially to a HDF5 file.

We can use the `h5py` library to create datasets, with each dataset corresponding to an array in `A`.

```
import h5py, numpy as np

A = [arr1, arr2, arr3]  # each arrX is a numpy array

with h5py.File('file.h5', 'w', libver='latest') as f:  # use 'latest' for performance

    for idx, arr in enumerate(A):
        dset = f.create_dataset(str(idx), shape=(240, 240), data=arr, chunks=(240, 240)
                                compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

I use `gzip` compression here for compatibility reasons, since it ships with every HDF5 installation. You may also wish to consider `blosc` & `lzf` filters. I also set `chunks` equal to `shape`, under the assumption you intend to read entire arrays rather than partial arrays.

The [h5py documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) is an excellent resource to improve your understanding of the HDF5 format, as the `h5py` API follows the C API closely.

Comment: Thank you this is great! I do have some follow-up qs for you (if you want I can post them as seperate qs): 
1. Is it storing each of the arrays onto the disk directly? 
2. Is it possible to append more arrays into this h5 file?
3. How can I read from this? I'm assuming each array has been tagged with a number?

Comment: @nababs, Yep, it might be worth asking as a separate question on bits about HDF5 you don't understand. The short answers to your question are 1) yes, 2) yes.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that setting the chunkshape the same as the dataset shape is normally a bad idea. In this case it works, but will fail if a chunk gets bigger than 4GB. Too large chunks also often have a negative impact on compression performance. Also creating that large amount of very small datasets isn't normally not recommendable (both for speed and compression efficiency)

Comment: @max9111, Excellent points. I'm not sure what the use case is. For example, extracting one dataset now and then, or extracting a range of datasets multiple times. We need more information from OP on how the data is used to provide further guidance. As we know, a list of `numpy` arrays is already pretty inefficient :).